# nginx won't restart with my config file

Tags: api, nginx, configuration

Restarting nginx :

```
# service nginx start
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] duplicate upstream "api" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

This is the config file :

```
upstream api{
        least_conn;
        server 127.0.0.1:5001 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=15s;
        server 127.0.0.1:5002 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=15s;
        server 127.0.0.1:5003 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=15s;
        server 127.0.0.1:5004 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=15s;
}


server {
        listen 192.168.10.33:80;
        allow 192.168.0.0/20;
        allow 127.0.0.1/32;
        deny all;

        server_name api api.my.intranet;
        location ^~ (/images/|/css/|/javascripts/) {
                root /var/www/myapi/public/;
                expires 30m;
        }

        # serve all other stuff from appserver
        location / {
                 if ($http_origin ~ (.*\.my\.intranet|.*\.my\.com) ) {
                       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;
                }

                # add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

                  expires off;
                  proxy_pass        http://api/;
                  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        }
}

server {
        listen 175.30.33.14:80;
        server_name api.my.com;
        return 301 https://api.my.com$request_uri;

}

server {
        listen 443;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/my.com.2014.chain;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/my.com.2014.key;

        server_tokens off; 

        server_name api api.my.com api.my.intranet;
        location ^~ (/images/|/css/|/javascripts/) {
                root /var/www/myapi/public/;
                expires 30d;
        }
        # serve all other stuff from appserver
        location / {
                 if ($http_origin ~ (.*\.my\.intranet|.*\.my\.com) ) {
                       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;
                }
                # add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

                  expires off;
                  proxy_pass http://api/;
                  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        }
        location /v2 {
                rewrite  ^/v2/(.*)  /$1 break;
                 if ($http_origin ~ (.*\.my\.intranet|.*\.my\.com) ) {
                       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;
                }
                # add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

                  expires off;
                  proxy_pass        http://192.168.10.8:3000/;
                  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        }
}
```

Do you see any problem ?

Answer (score 0):

a backup file: defuault.backup was in the same folder which created a conflict !